# if i select value in select box other text will appear in the input field

Tags: php, jquery

I create an `array[]` entry of name and place is there any way if i `select value` in `select box` the `country` of selected value will appear to the `input field` value automatically.

for example I select `Marjohn bebeloni` as select box value, then `china` will automatic appear in the `input field`

```
<?php
  $names = array('Ireneo Crodua' => 'Australia', 
                 'Almads Bangal' => 'India', 
                 'Rechard Canonigo' => 'America',
                 'Marjohn bebeloni' => 'China'
  );

?>


<form action="post">

  <p><label>Select Name</label>
    <select>
      <?php 
        foreach($names as $name => $place){
          echo "<option>" . $name . "</option>";
        }
      ?>

    </select>
  </p>


  <p><label>Place</label><input name="place" value="" /></p>


</form>
```

Comment: You can put the name of place in `<option value="place_name"` and onChange put the value in input field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<p><label>Select Name</label>
    <select>
      <?php 
        foreach($names as $name => $place){
          echo "<option value='" . $place . "'>" . $name . "</option>";
        }
      ?>

    </select>
  </p>


  <p><label>Place</label><input name="place" value="" /></p>
```

and use below jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
     $('input[name=place]').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

esiest way to do ;)

```
<select id="selectsomething">
  <?php 
    foreach($names as $name => $place){
      echo "<option foo=\"$place\">" . $name . "</option>";
    }
  ?>

</select>
```

in JS you can write this finction

```
$('#selectsomething').onchange(function(){
    $('#textfield').val($(this).attr("foo"));
`});`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it

```
 <?php
   $names = array('Ireneo Crodua' => 'Australia', 
                  'Almads Bangal' => 'India', 
                  'Rechard Canonigo' => 'America',
                  'Marjohn bebeloni' => 'China'
   );

 ?>
 <form action="post">

   <p><label>Select Name</label>
     <select id="select">
       <?php 
         foreach($names as $name => $place){
           echo "<option value='$place'>" . $name . "</option>";
         }
       ?>

     </select>
   </p>


   <p><label>Place</label><input id="place" name="place" value="" /></p>
   <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#select').change(function(){
           $('#place').val($(this).val());
       });
   });

   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('select').on('change',function(){
     $('input[name=place]').val($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Hope it will work for you.